# Why QFileIconProvider is included in QtWidgets

Tags: c++, qt

Are there any essential reasons why `QFileIconProvider`([link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfileiconprovider.html)) was included in `QtWidgets` library instead of `QtCore`? That class is really usable and great in some cases, but its location in `QtWidgets` makes my QML application depending on that library just because of one class.

Comment: This looks more like a bug report or feature request for the Qt project than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Mat, thanks, great idea! But, maybe, there really are some reasons.

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't. But knowing it won't get rid of that dependency (i.e. might satisfy your curiosity but won't help you with your code/project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out: This looks more like a bug report or feature request for the Qt project than a Stack Overflow question.

However, the answer isn't so hard to guess: Qt isn't primarily QML. Even in Qt 5 QML is some sort of addon to Qt. In pure C++/Qt applications  QFileIconProvider in QtCore would not make any sense. It is a helper class for QFileSystemModel, which only makes sense with a view class, which of course are located in QtWidgets. Naturally you could ask, if QFileSystemModel needs to be in QtWidgets, but to do this, I recommend the qt-interest mailing list.
http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo